# error in converting matrix in txt file to matrix in numpy form

Tags: python

i am extracting matrix from a txt file like this sample (it is huge one) :
[   1,   1]: 3.890e-004 [   1,   2]: 0.000e+000 [   1,   3]: 0.000e+000 [   1,   4]: 0.000e+000 [   1,   5]: 0.000e+000 [   1,   6]: 0.000e+000 [   1,   7]: 9.732e-005 [   1,   8]: 0.000e+000 [   1,   9]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  10]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  11]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  12]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  13]: 9.735e-005 [   1,  14]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  15]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  16]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  17]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  18]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  19]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  20]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  21]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  22]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  23]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  24]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  25]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  26]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  27]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  28]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  29]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  30]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  31]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  32]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  33]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  34]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  35]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  36]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  37]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  38]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  39]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  40]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  41]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  42]: 0.000e+000 [   1,  43]: 0.000e+000 .....................................................
.............................................................................................
[6567,6562]: 0.000e+000 [6567,6563]: 0.000e+000 [6567,6564]: 0.000e+000 [6567,6565]: 0.000e+000 [6567,6566]: 0.000e+000 [6567,6567]: 2.960e-020
using next code:

```
n=6567
with open("stiff_matrix.txt") as file:
data = file.read()

kmat = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
for x, y, value in re.findall(r'\[\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\s*\]: ([0-9e+.]+)', data):
    if value :
        kmat[int(x)-1][int(y)-1] = float(value)
```

it keep telling me :
"couldn't convert string to float: 8.259e" known that the shown file is induced automatically by another application (no human interface in it)

Comment: It would be interesting to see the fragment of your data that is causing the issue. Have you considered trying to find the `x` and `y` value when the error occurs, and looking it up in your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`8.259e` is wrong number expression. I guess you mean `8.259`.You can solve it by the example bellow.

```py
number = '8.259e'
number = float(number.strip('e'))
print(number)
```

You will get output `8.259`

And your regex is not completely right. You can try `r'\[\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\s*\]: (.*?) '` to match the result again.

**Note**: there is a space between `)` and `'` at the end of the regex I gave.

In your example, `3.890e` is matched in line 1 in the file, however, `3.890e-004` is expected
result.

Comment: awesome ..... it worked out neatly ...ths